Partition function expression from a discrete Hubbard-Stratonovich transformation
$\DeclareMathOperator{tr}{tr}$ This question is about a very specific (but very mysterious to me) detail. In some quantum Monte Carlo methods such as determinant QMC, the partition function $Z = \tr e^{-\beta H}$ is expressed as an average over determinants of one-body matrices (rather than exponentially large operators). For example, following dos Santos (PRB, 1993) (see also Scaletter et al. (PRB, 1999)), consider the attractive Fermi-Hubbard model over $N$ sites:
$$H = -t \sum_{\langle i,j \rangle, \sigma} (c_{i\sigma}^\dagger c_{j\sigma} + c_{j\sigma}^\dagger c_{i\sigma}) - \mu \sum_{i,\sigma} n_{i\sigma} - |U| \sum_{i=1}^N \left(n_{i\uparrow} - \frac{1}{2}\right) \left(n_{i\downarrow} - \frac{1}{2}\right).$$
First, the Trotter-Suzuki formula is used to break up the exponential of $H = \mathcal{K} + \mathcal{V}$ into more manageable terms:
$$e^{-\beta H} \approx \prod_{\ell=1}^L e^{-\Delta\tau \mathcal{K}} e^{-\Delta\tau \mathcal{V}},$$
where $\Delta\tau = \beta/L$ and the approximation error is of order $\Delta\tau^2$. We will ignore this Trotter error in the subsequent derivations.
A form of the discrete Hubbard-Stratonovich transformation is then applied to express the interaction $e^{-\Delta\tau \mathcal{V}}$ in terms of noninteracting operators coupled to an auxiliary $N$-mode Ising field:
$$\exp\left[+\Delta\tau |U| \left(n_{i\uparrow} - \frac{1}{2}\right) \left(n_{i\downarrow} - \frac{1}{2}\right)\right] = \frac{1}{2} e^{-\Delta\tau |U|/4} \sum_{s_i = \pm 1} \exp\left[\Delta\tau\lambda s_i (n_{i\uparrow} + n_{i\downarrow} - 1)\right],$$
where $\lambda \in \mathbb{R}$ is such that $\cosh(\Delta\tau\lambda) = e^{\Delta\tau |U|/2}$.1 Assigning an independent Ising field for each imaginary-time slice $s_{i\ell} = \pm 1$, we get
$$Z = \left( \frac{1}{2} e^{-\Delta\tau |U|/4} \right)^{NL} \sum_{\{s_{i\ell}\}} \tr \prod_{\sigma\in\{\uparrow,\downarrow\}} \prod_{\ell=1}^L D^\sigma_\ell,$$
where dos Santos claims that
$$D^\sigma_\ell = \exp\left(-\Delta\tau \sum_{i,j} K_{ij} c_{i\sigma}^\dagger c_{j\sigma}\right) \exp\left(-\Delta\tau \sum_{i,j} V_{ij}(\ell) c_{i\sigma}^\dagger c_{j\sigma}\right),$$
with the $N \times N$ matrices $K$ and $V(\ell)$ defined as2
$$K_{ij} = \begin{cases}
-t & \text{if $i, j$ are adjacent,}\\
0 & \text{otherwise,}
\end{cases}$$
$$V_{ij}(\ell) = -\delta_{ij}\left(\frac{1}{2} \lambda s_{i\ell} + \mu\right).$$
My confusion: At this step, I am not seeing how $V(\ell)$ yields the desired operators from the HS transformation, which should presumably be
$$\exp\left[\Delta\tau\lambda \sum_i s_{i\ell} \left(n_{i\sigma} - \frac{1}{2}\right)\right]. \quad \text{(Desired)}$$
However, using the form of $V(\ell)$ given, it seems that the term would instead look like
$$\exp\left(\Delta\tau\lambda \sum_i s_{i\ell} n_{i\sigma} / 2\right), \quad \text{(Obtained by form of $V(\ell)$ above)}$$
which is not the same operator. (I have no issue with the hopping and chemical potential terms, as they look correct).
The upshot of this discrepancy is that the partition function is finally transformed, using the trace-determinant identity for free fermions, into
$$Z = \left( \frac{1}{2} e^{-\Delta\tau |U|/4} \right)^{NL} \sum_{\{s_{i\ell}\}} \prod_\sigma \det(M(\{s_{i\ell}\})),$$
where $M(\{s_{i\ell}\}) = I + \prod_{\ell=1}^L B_\ell$ is the $N \times N$ matrix with each $B_\ell = e^{-\Delta\tau K} e^{-\Delta\tau V(\ell)}$. However, for the reasons I outlined above, this seems to give the incorrect expression for the decoupled interaction terms. Instead, it seems like one should define $V_{ij}(\ell) = -\delta_{ij}(\lambda s_{i\ell} + \mu)$, and then we get
$$Z = \left( \frac{1}{2} e^{-\Delta\tau |U|/4} \right)^{NL} \sum_{\{s_{i\ell}\}} \exp\left(-\Delta\tau\lambda \sum_{i=1}^N \sum_{\ell=1}^L s_{i\ell}\right) \prod_\sigma \det(M(\{s_{i\ell}\})).$$
Thus rather than a a simple product of determinants, it seems we instead get this additional positive factor that depends on the sum of all the auxiliary Ising variables.3 However I never see DQMC for the attractive Hubbard model expressed in this way, so I am wondering if authors are merely being terse with the details in their equations, or if I am misunderstanding something in the derivation.
1 For the repulsive Hubbard model, where the interaction has sign $+|U|$, the form of the HS transformation has the spin operator $(n_{i\uparrow} - n_{i\downarrow})$ appearing on the RHS to ensure $\lambda \in \mathbb{R}$, rather than $(n_{i\uparrow} + n_{i\downarrow} - 1)$. The lack of c-number in the repulsive case means that my question does not apply in that setting.
2 I believe dos Santos has a sign error in the HS transformation, propagated due to a typo in the original Hirsch (1983) paper.
3 It seems the literature also never writes down the overall prefactor of $\left( \frac{1}{2} e^{-\Delta\tau |U|/4} \right)^{NL}$ in their final equations for $Z$, although this is less egregious because it does not depend on the Ising variables and so doesn't matter when applied to algorithms to sample from the partition function.

The expressions are difficult to read when you use $e^{...}$. Rather use $\exp(...)$.
